# Does one Kendo UI license cover all controls?

Tags: kendo-ui

Does a Kendo UI license cover all parts including Kendo UI controls for Angular, Kendo UI controls for jQuery, Kendo UI controls for React etc. or do we have to purchase each license separate?

If our team has to buy separate licenses for Kendo UI controls for Angular and Kendo UI controls for jQuery, where is the pricing information given?

P.S.

For the time being, our team needs only Kendo UI controls for AngularJS.

Comment: They have a 1-800 number.  Ring them!

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/purchase.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes - at the moment Kendo UI [license](https://www.telerik.com/purchase.aspx) includes support for jQuery, AngularJS, Angular2+, React and Vue libraries. It also covers ASP.NET AJAX, ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Core, Silverlight, Xamarin, UWP, WPF and WinForms controls.
Yet these offerings may change and indeed it is always a better decision to contact them directly for detailed latest information about such questions.